# App terminated attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

This process is sending eMails, and it works fine, but the framework wants the body of the email to be an NSArray. So I try to convert the NSString to a NSDictionary to include with the NSArray here:

```
NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
    message,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey, nil];
```

then I implement that here:

```
smtpTestMessage.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObject:plainPart];
```

Overall, here is my code:

```
NSLog(@"Start eMail");


SKPSMTPMessage *smtpTestMessage = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
smtpTestMessage.fromEmail = @"***@gmail.com";
smtpTestMessage.toEmail = @"***@yahoo.com";
smtpTestMessage.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
smtpTestMessage.requiresAuth = YES;
smtpTestMessage.login = @"***@gmail.com";
smtpTestMessage.pass = @"***";
smtpTestMessage.subject = @"***";
smtpTestMessage.wantsSecure = YES;

smtpTestMessage.delegate = self;

NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
    message,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey, nil];


smtpTestMessage.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObject:plainPart];

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",message];

[smtpTestMessage send];
NSLog(@"sent");
```

But sadly enough, when I run the app, the eMail gets to the last stage... Then the app terminates saying

```
2013-10-15 00:43:50.512 BullyBox[3662:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f61ae8b 0x399156c7 0x2f5540cb 0x2f556749 0xc77f3 0x31dd555f 0x31dd54fb 0x31dd54cb 0x31dc10f3 0x31dd4f13 0x31dd4bdd 0x31dcfc09 0x31da4f59 0x31da3747 0x2f5e5f27 0x2f5e53ef 0x2f5e3bdf 0x2f54e541 0x2f54e323 0x342852eb 0x31e051e5 0xc91b5 0x39e0eab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**EDIT**

Now I keep getting the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you for even reading this! xD <3

Comment: Now I keep getting the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `plainPart` is created successfully and not a nil.

Comment: I apologize, but how does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to judge but if I had to guess `plainPart` is not getting created. Why do I think this? Let's take a look at the error:

`[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]:`

This points to an alloc/init sequence of calls. The only place in the code you shared where you are allocating an array is here:

`smtpTestMessage.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObject:plainPart];`

Therefore, if you are trying to create an array with a nil object, `plainPart`, then it makes sense why you are getting an error about trying to insert a nil object at location 0.

Try setting a breakpoint right at this call in your code. This will help you narrow down where the crash happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here

```
 NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
message,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey, nil];
```

but based on you naming convention you are storing a key in a value location. Also you could switch to the modern objective-C syntax

```
 NSDictionary *plainPart =  @{
                                message: kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
 kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey: kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey
 };
```

This is equivalent to what you wrote, but more readable. As stated in the other answers it look like there is a problem with the creation of plainPart. Hopefully looking at this should make it easier to debug.

Comment: That sounded like it would work, but when I ran it, I still got: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'

Comment: But a breakpoint in and look at the values for you keys and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Check first this line `smtpTestMessage.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObject:plainPart];`.
Whether it is `smtpTestMessage`allocated if yes then check any data exist inside this or not

Comment: Your problem seems to be minor. Please check??